# exact timing keep-alive in linux TCP/IP programming

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, keep-alive

as I know there's two ways to resolving [the Half-Open connection problem](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html). One is the heartbeat tech. and the other, is my problem: *keep-alive*.

I know that *keep-alive* have [three properties](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html) like:

tcp_keepalive_time \ tcp_keepalive_intvl \ tcp_keepalive_probes.

And I set them to

5secs \ 1sec \ 10

Which means that the keepalive routines wait for 5 seconds before sending the first keepalive probe, and then resend it every 1 seconds. If no ACK response is received for 10 consecutive times, the connection is marked as broken.

I do enabled *keep-alive* and set these properties for it in my linux C++ code by calling **setsockopt()**,  and sometimes, it works fine as follows:

[image: ten consecutive times]

But in other time, the *keep-alive* **DOES NOT** send, and the retransmission msg has been sent and stucked instead:

[image]

It just sending 7-times(the time between each resend is larger than 1sec, almost 2~5secs). And then stucked for a long time.

So why TCP *keep-alive* does not send sometimes? And how can I make sure that *keep-alive* probe can always been sent. Should I do someting else?

Thanks for all of your helping.

**EDIT**

1. As @West said that the stuck is come from exponential backoff after a unacknowledged transmission, but why the retransmission stuck the process of sending *keep-alive* probe? is there any priority or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to me like exponential backoff after an unacknowledged transmission. TCP_MAXRT will allow you to set how long you want to wait before giving up on trying to transmit. TM_TCP_MAX_REXMIT will let you set the max number of retries.

Comment: I'm a little bit confusing, does the value of TCP_MAXRT really affect transmission of *keep-alive*? Can you clarify that, thanks so much.

Comment: I'm not sure this is keep alive at all. I think this might be exponential backoff for regular retransmission. Thats why I was suggesting those.

Comment: @billhoo: I think he's saying yes. Instead of sending more keep-alives, it waits for an ACK of the keep-alive it already sent, which is a different set of timers. It's usually simpler to have the keep-alive in your app: When idle, send a message every N seconds, abort if no reply after X seconds.

Comment: @BraveNewCurrency got it, but we cannot change our app's protocol right now, so I'll try to control the retransmission things and give a feedback here.

Comment: @West I finally find out that the priority of keep-alive probe is less than retransmission packets, so if ACK is not transmit successfully, the retransmission is triggered and the first keep-alive probe can never be sent. That's why I saw sometimes it works well and in other time it failed. Thanks for all of your helping :)